# Assign a variable column name in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to do the following:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Test = c(1:100))
var <- "TestPlusOne"

#METHOD 1
dt[, (var) := Test + 1][, c("TestPlusOne")]

#METHOD 2
dt[, .(TestPlusOne = Test + 1)]
```

I would like to do what I did in `#METHOD 2`, but with a variable `TestPlusOne`, i.e. I would like to pass a column name in the variable `var` that defines the name. In the first `#METHOD 1`, the actual data table changes, but that is a side-effect that I would like to prevent.

Is it possible to change `#METHOD 2` such that the column name is given by the string in `var`?

Additional information: I do **not** want to add another column to **dt**, nor do I want to deep copy the object **dt** to achieve it, because it seems rather inefficient. I would like to do it in `#METHOD 2`. But I can't seem to pinpoint how to do that.

Comment: This already works, right? `dt[, (var) := Test + 1]` What are you looking for?

Comment: Or do you want to change both data and column name at once? I'd suggest using `setnames` to change the column name by reference.

Comment: Yes, that already works, but the problem is, that the assignment `:=` changes the `dt`. So the object dt gets changed, I do -not- want that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is with `setNames()`:

```
dt[, setNames(.(Test + 1), var)]
```

Could also use this subsetting+chaining hack, although it probably beats the purpose.

```
dt[TRUE][, (var) := Test + 1][, "TestPlusOne"]
# or as nicola suggests
copy(dt)[, (var) := Test + 1][, "TestPlusOne"]
```

A possibility

```
setnames(data.table(dt$Test + 1), var)[]
```

Which leads to

```
dt[, setnames(data.table(Test + 1), var)]
```

Comment: Instead of `dt[TRUE]`, I'd suggest the cleaner (and probably more efficient) `copy(dt)`.